# kmalloc debugging information

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, kernel

I just tried adding debugging information in kmalloc returned pointer but after my changes my kernel is not coming up. i have changes as follows :-
Suppose some module request a memory of x size , then in kmalloc i increased the size with (x+ debug_information).
At the beginning of memory allocated pointer I have stored following information
calling function address(4 Byte),size(4byte), and header(byte) and at end memory size one footer was added and address returned to calling module is (ptr +12).
Now while free memory using kfree , i am decreasing  pointer address by 12 bytes (ptr -12).

Now after doing these changes my kernel is not coming up.
Even i done simple code changes like increase  requested memory of size (requested_size +4), return pointer to module of ptr +4,
while freeing memory decrease this pointer with 4, now this also not working .
What could be possible issue, why we can not add debug information before and after kmalloc returned pointer ?

Comment: Possibly the pointer returned should be aligned at 8 or 16 bytes boundary...? Try extending your header by 4 bytes.

Comment: its also not working with 8,16 and 32 alignment, any other idea ?